# How can I use connection pool in aiomysql

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I just don't know what to do to reuse aiomysql connection pool by reading the [aiohttp examples](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql/blob/master/examples/example_pool.py) or by google.
Here is my code

```
import aiomysql
import asyncio


async def select(loop, sql):
    pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306,
                                      user='root', password='123456',
                                      db='test', loop=loop)
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(sql)
            r = await cur.fetchone()
            print(r)


async def insert(loop, sql):
    pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306,
                                      user='root', password='123456',
                                      db='test', loop=loop)
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(sql)
            await conn.commit()


async def main(loop):
    c1 = select(loop=loop, sql='select * from minifw')
    c2 = insert(loop=loop, sql="insert into minifw (name) values ('hello')")
    tasks = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(c1),
        asyncio.ensure_future(c2)
    ]
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cur_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    cur_loop.run_until_complete(main(cur_loop))
```

If i run this code, the `create_pool` will be executed twice.So I want to know how to change this code to reuse aiomysql connecton pool.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define pool in main func, like this:

```
import aiomysql
import asyncio


async def select(loop, sql, pool):
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(sql)
            r = await cur.fetchone()
            print(r)


async def insert(loop, sql, pool):
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(sql)
            await conn.commit()


async def main(loop):
    pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port=3306,
        user='root',
        password='123456',
        db='test',
        loop=loop)
    c1 = select(loop=loop, sql='select * from minifw limit 1', pool=pool)
    c2 = insert(loop=loop, sql="insert into minifw (name) values ('hello')", pool=pool)

    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(c1), asyncio.ensure_future(c2)]
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cur_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    cur_loop.run_until_complete(main(cur_loop))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works  - but isn't the whole idea of pool is to return multiple cursors for multiple tasks?

Comment: The pool will return two different connections for the two queries.  A pool creates multiple connections and you retrieve one of them with the acquire() call.

Comment: hey i know it's a bit old, but in case anyone's still here: why are you passing loop as an argument to the select and insert methods, you're not using it anyhow?