Cannot acquire connection after closing pool
When I call functions an error occurs
RuntimeError: Cannot acquire connection after closing pool
but I don't close the pool anywhere
from aiomysql import create_pool, Cursor
import asyncio
from env import DATABASE, HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD


class Table:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        l = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.pool = l.run_until_complete(create_pool(
            host=HOST,
            port=PORT,
            user=USER,
            password=PASSWORD,
            db=DATABASE,
            cursorclass=Cursor,
            autocommit=True,
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop(),
            maxsize=15
        ))


    async def f(self):
        async with self.pool as pool:
            async with pool.acquire() as conn:
                async with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                    QUERY = f"""SELECT 1;"""
                    await cursor.execute(QUERY, (user_id))
                    return (await cursor.fetchone())[0]

Traceback:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\main.py", line 137, in start
    test = await table.f()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\main.py", line 43, in f
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiomysql\utils.py", line 134, in __aenter__
    self._conn = await self._coro
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiomysql\pool.py", line 139, in _acquire
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot acquire connection after closing pool")
RuntimeError: Cannot acquire connection after closing pool


Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

It would help if you posted the full error trace, not just the final error message. Otherwise it's hard to tell where the issue is. But in general a with statement will call close on your behalf when it goes out of scope. So when you return from a

@DavidWaterworth added

You should click edit under your original question and add it there - you've added as an answer

(I've edited it for you)

@DavidWaterworth Perhaps this could be useful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481826/how-can-i-use-connection-pool-in-aiomysql
but I still don't understand why the error

Decided this way
from aiomysql import create_pool, Cursor
import asyncio
from env import DATABASE, HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD


class Table:
    def __init__(self, loop=asyncio.get_event_loop(), maxsize=15) -> None:
        self.pool = None
        self.loop = loop
        self.maxsize = maxsize


    async def create_pool(self):
        self.pool = await create_pool(
            host=HOST,
            port=PORT,
            user=USER,
            password=PASSWORD,
            db=DATABASE,
            loop=self.loop,
            autocommit=True,
            cursorclass=Cursor,
            maxsize=self.maxsize
        )


    async def f(self):
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                QUERY = f"""SELECT 1;"""
                await cursor.execute(QUERY, (user_id))
                return (await cursor.fetchone())[0]


async def main():
    table = Table()
    await table.create_pool()
    print(await table.f()) #True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())

